# Auto Layout Unavailable Features

Tags: ios, xcode, layout

I have quite a few viewcontrollers in my storyboard and and was auto layouting one of them, when this weird thing happened; after choosing a label or the view itself, i couldn't seem to update its frame, because the feature was for some reasons unavailable. After many attempt in fixing the problem, i thought "Maybe i can solve the problem by restarting the program", so that i did and then suddenly, the problem was solved. For 2 minutes, where it then started again. I tryed restarting xcode again, but this time, nothing was solved. Not even for a short period of time. And that's where i am now.

[here's a picture of the mentioned error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/10ysim3njr5lvii/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202015-03-19%20kl.%2021.53.45.png)

So if you have any idea what might cause this problem, feel free to inform me :)

Comment: If the frame is already correct then you can't update it in that menu...

Comment: I feel a bit dumb right now, but thank you :)

Comment: Wain's comment should be an answer

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter noted your frame seems correctly placed (no orange dotted lines). Do you actually have a warning saying your frame will be different at runtime?